# Codenameone new GUI Builder null pointer when trying to assign image to button

Tags: codenameone

When using the new GUI Builder (CN1 plugin v3.6.0) I can attach an image from my res file to a Button and it appears in the preview nicely 
[image: button showing image from res file]
but when I try to run the code in the Simulator I get a NullPointerException on the line

```
  gui_ordersButton.setIcon(resourceObjectInstance.getImage("Orders.png"));
```

As this is in the magic "do not edit below this line" block how can I fix this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two elements can throw a null pointer from this exact line:

gui_ordersButton.setIcon(resourceObjectInstance.getImage("Orders.png"));

`gui_ordersButton` or `resourceObjectInstance`. If the image isn't available in the resources the null pointer will come from the `setIcon` method.

I'm guessing `resourceObjectInstance` is null because you changed something about the way resources are loaded in the default project or you used the constructor of the form that passes null as the resources object.

Comment: Hi Shai, yes were right, resourceObjectInstance was null so adding this in the init() routine fixed it:          theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");    Thanks for your help once again!